# Capitalization of tussenvoegsel at start of sentence

Tags: capitalization

What is the proper capitalization of [tussenvoegsel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tussenvoegsel) at the start of a sentence? For instance, if we were talking about Vincent van Gogh would we say:

"Van Gogh was an artist."

or

"van Gogh was an artist."

The following article did *not* capitalize the tussenvoegsel which is why I bring up this question. http://phys.org/news/2015-10-ornithomimus-dinosaur-tail-feathers-skin.html

Comment: See [this Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=_START_+*+Gogh&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t2%3B%2C_START_%20*%20Gogh%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3B_START_%20Van%20Gogh%3B%2Cc0%3B%3B_START_%20van%20Gogh%3B%2Cc0%3B%3B_START_%20See%20Gogh%3B%2Cc0%3B%3B_START_%20Von%20Gogh%3B%2Cc0)

Comment: I would vote for capitalization.

Comment: It is common practice to capitalise it, I would say.